# Find all unit in a space (mod m) using any complete set of residues

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

In my Number Theory class, we have never learned about rings. I believe "unit" is a term for a ring. In this example, we are looking to find units at the space $\frac{Z}{7Z}$ using any complete set of residues. I think we know that 1 is a unit because any number (mod 7) times its inverse is 1, but not sure if that's really how it works. I'm pretty sure this is a ring problem and not number theory. Help would be appreciated! I don't want the answer to this, just a clarification on what the question means!

Comment: A unit in a ring is any element that has a multiplicative inverse.  Thus, $1$ is always a unit and $0$ never is.  In $\mathbb Z/\4\mathbb Z$ the units are $\{1,3\}$ and so on.  See, e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory))

Comment: So there isnt "the" unit 1 like in multiplication. It can be anything that has an inverse?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  The units in the integers are $\pn 1$ for example.

Comment: Sorry, that should have read $\{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: @lulu So for the set of residues {1,2,3,4,5,6} mod 7, all of them are units since they all have inverses. Would that be correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.